# Why can't I update an image using CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have a problem with updating an image, a user's avatar. I am using CarrierWave and have two models: `profile` and `user`.

On the `user#show` page, I have a form for `profile`, in which I have `file_field`. Profile belongs to User. Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @user.profile do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br/>
      <%= f.submit "Change Avatar"  %><br/>
      <% end %>
```

After submiting, the image is not updated. In the server logs I see:

```
Processing by ProfilesController#update as HTML   Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"lHbhHK9SLIiTUuBJAAUyz0CSSC1tUhbE0oD2An2QEEY=",
"profile"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa60ff43b40
@original_filename="P1010056.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[avatar]\";
filename=\"P1010056.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
@tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/kq/gjn7ljfx1wx418ptwnbb46vr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120213-2399-sm0m9c>>},
"commit"=>"Change Avatar", "id"=>"1"}
```

This is my profile update action:

```
def update
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you trimmed `"avatar"=>#>` what class was the value? Also, in your model are you telling it to use something to handle the uploaded file?

Comment: What i exactly should to do to handle the uploaded file, also if i want to change other model fields, as :name and other , they are not changed too

Comment: What does "not updated" mean? Where are you storing the image? If you go there, do you see it?

Comment: I found a problem. It was my stupid mistake. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Could you please describe the solution Pavel?

Comment: I hate this when they say "I found the problem" and after that disappear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the multipart attribute in the form set to true:

```
<%= form_for @user.profile, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br/>
  <%= f.submit "Change Avatar"  %><br/>
<% end %>
```

Have you also checked if you have set `attr_accessible` for the avatar attribute in the model? Your model might not have mass-assignment enabled. Make sure you have this in your `Profile` model:

`attr_accessible :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar`

Comment: I have added multi part and attr_accessible, but it doesnt help

Comment: @Dia you donot need to include `multipart` for the `form_for` , this option is for simple forms and `form_tag` , have a look at point 5 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html